# Magnific Popup Jquery: Ajax Popup is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I am trying to show a web page content in popup window using [Magnific Popup jquery](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/)

I am using `ajax` type to show content.

I tried the below code.

**HTML:**

```
<a class="ajax" href="http://www.google.com">
        Text
</a>
```

**JQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.ajax').magnificPopup({
                delegate: 'a',
                type: 'ajax',
                alignTop: true,
                overflowY: 'scroll' // as we know that popup content is tall we set scroll overflow by default to avoid jump
            }
        }

    });
        });
</script>
```

Please check the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0d5qp2vk/)

In terms of Jquery I am a novice. What I did wrong here?

Comment: @LShetty it is not opening in popup window. You just changed the url.

Answer (score 0):

The problem are your external links. they can't be load/interpreted correctly cause the wrong MIME type.

```
http://dimsemenov-static.s3.amazonaws.com/dist/magnific-popup.css
http://dimsemenov-static.s3.amazonaws.com/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/0d5qp2vk/3/) is the fiddle with working external resources.

The "real" problem is that it don't work with a link on an other origin.

> ERROR: Refused to display 'https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.